# Parallelizing prime generator in c++

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, primes

This is a prime generator program, it works fine when number of processors `int numProc` is 1, but if user sepcifies that there are multiple processors, i want to use a parallellized version of primes, so that the generating would be distributed to a number of processes.

*NOTE: I have taken out flag handling and menu display code in int main to save space*

Code:

```
#define NUMITERS 1
#define MAXSIZE 500000
#define MAXNUMPROCS 64
#define PRIME(num) (2*(num) + 3)
#define NUM(prime) (((prime) - 3)/2)

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int lastPrime, count;      /* Last Prime and Number of Primes Found */
int size = 100000;           /* Number of numbers to test for prime */
int numProcs = 5;          /* Number of processors */
FILE *out = NULL;          /* File to output primes to */
char *flags;               /* Array of primes (odd numbers only) 
                              i.e. flags[0] corresponds to 3
                              flags[1] corresponds to 5
                              flags[n] corresponds to 2*n+3
                              flags[i] is TRUE if i is a prime */

void primes(void);              /* procedure prototype */
void parallelPrimes(void);      /* procedure prototype */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    clock_t t;
t = clock();
    int i, opt;
    /* MENU DISPLAY and flag operations here */

    if (numProcs == 1) 
      primes();   /* Call  primes routine */
    else
      parallelPrimes(); /* call multi-threaded/parallelized

    /* print out all of the primes found */
    if (out != NULL) {
      int i;
      fprintf(out, "2\n");
      for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    if (flags[i])
      fprintf(out, "%d\n", PRIME(i));
    }

    free(flags);
    printf(" Number of primes = %d, largest prime = %d\n", count, lastPrime);
    t = clock() - t;
printf ("It took me %d clicks (%f seconds).\n",t,((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}

void primes()
{
    int i,iter, prime, div1, div2, rem;
    for (iter=0; iter < NUMITERS; ++iter)      
        {
            count = 0;
            lastPrime = 0;

            for (i=0; i < size; ++i) {    /* For every odd number */
            prime = PRIME(i);              
                div1=1;
                do {                            
                    div1 += 2;            /* Divide by 3, 5, 7, ... */
                    div2 = prime / div1;  /* Find the dividend */
                    rem = prime % div1;   /* Find remainder */
                } while (rem != 0 && div1 <= div2); 

                if (rem != 0 || div1 == prime) {
                    /* prime is really a prime */
                    flags[i] = TRUE;
                    count++;                   
                    lastPrime = prime;
                } else {
                    /* prime is not a prime */
                    flags[i] = FALSE;         
                }
            }
        }
}
```

So far I have tried using `#include<omp.h>` in the following function:

```
void parallelPrimes()
{

    int i;
    int iter, prime;
    int div1, div2, rem;

    for (iter=0; iter < NUMITERS; ++iter)      
        /*  
           Don't parallelize this loop??? */
        {
            count = 0;
            lastPrime = 0;
            omp_set_num_threads(numProcs);
            #pragma omp parallel
            int ID = omp_get_thread_num();
                    #pragma omp for
                    for (i=0; i < size; ++i) {    /* For every odd number */
                            prime = PRIME(i);              
                /* Keep searching for divisor until rem == 0 (i.e. non prime),
                   or we've reached the sqrt of prime (when div1 > div2) */

                            div1=1;
                            do {                            
                               div1 += 2;            /* Divide by 3, 5, 7, ... */
                               div2 = prime / div1;  /* Find the dividend */
                               rem = prime % div1;   /* Find remainder */
                                } while (rem != 0 && div1 <= div2); 

                           if (rem != 0 || div1 == prime) {
                           /* prime is really a prime */

                               flags[i] = TRUE;
                               count++;                   
                               lastPrime = prime;
                           } else {
                                /* prime is not a prime */
                               flags[i] = FALSE;         
                                  }
                           }
               }
    }
```

but its actually slower than the non-parallelized function `primes()` , am i implementing parallelism in this function incorrectly?

Comment: This looks like C and not C++, are you certain about your tags? Also what is your specific question here, we won't write you that function. Did you try anything so far? Then show it please.

Comment: i know this was not part of your question, but a way to speed up the serial solution would be to store found primes in a list and only test against 2 and the primes already found. this would add space complexity, but reduce time complexity dramatically(especially when your going for big primes). i would suggest optimizing the serial version before going for a (nontrivial when efficient) parallel solution. if you are going for it though, you should take a look at [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), a implicit threading library. Available [docs](http://openmp.org/wp/resources/)

Comment: @PlasmaHH I have edited the tags and added my attempt at the fucntion

Comment: @Carson Thanks for the suggestion, I would have to look at that once I figure out parallelisim . I'm already trying to use OpenMP, I have added a function called parallelPrimes() in OP

Comment: if you have parts of you program you want to parallelize and parts that you want tto be serial. you can toggle that with `#pragma omp parallel`(which you already use) and `#pragma omp single`. This will avoid race conditions at certain points of the code. ([examples](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-FB38434E-65CF-4665-8725-486D6B0B2475.htm))

Comment: also, which compiler/ide are you using? be sure to include -fopenmp as an argument to gcc. if it's netbeans i suggest switching to a different ide. nah, just kidding. [Here](http://programmers-journal.blogspot.de/2013/09/netbeans-ide-configuration-for-openmpi.html) is a tutorial on how to integrate it.

Comment: @Carson I'm using gcc/geany, I already have -fopenmp set up in my compile config. Where would I use `#pragma omp single` to prevent race conditions??

Comment: you do not have to do that here. What you would have to do here, if you want to parallelize the outer loop is move the #pragma out of the loop, directly in front of it.

Comment: @Carson i did that, and somehow parallelprimes() is always slower than primes() even if i put it #pragma after the loop

Comment: Well your prime number calculator isn't efficent to begin with. If your issue is the prime generator being too slow, rewrite it as a O(n) function for a start. If what you want is experiment with parallel computing, that's another matter.

Comment: @Sebastien yes, my main concern is experimenting with parallel computing. i only mentioned the speed issue because shouldn't the parallel function be faster than the unparallel function? Or am i implementing parallelisim incorrectly?

Comment: It depends on a lot of factor but in a nut shell, parallel computing has an overhead cost. If that cost is bigger than the gain, it will be slower. OpenMP is far behind in my memory though so I'd be hard pressed to say what is it's overhead. But if I take a pure C approach with fork, you would need to prepare a mutex flag (shared memory between the parent and the childrens) which takes time. Each thread would have to poll it and finish if one thread found a divisor to your candidate. Costly unless you want the 10000th prime number

Comment: @Sebastien I'm actually aiming for generating 100000 numbers and writing them to a file, so should I drop parallelisim and switch to multithreading?

Comment: Multithreading is hard. Start with fork (or stick with openMP). Besides, how many CPUs do you have to do that?

Comment: and you will most probably face int overflow problems...

Comment: @sebastien 5  cpus. i think ill stick with openMP, but i still don't know how to implement it correctly in my function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primes+c (83 questions). http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[primes]+parallel+is%3Aquestion (14 questions).

Answer (score 2):

[edited] I recommended looking at [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/)'s example 'primes'. But I admit, it's not an easy task to port it to OpenMP.

It uses `parallel_reduce` (for counting the primes) with a custom `SieveRange`, though it still can be translated to `omp parallel` because what the range does essentially is:

```
    NumberType middle = r.my_begin + (r.my_end-r.my_begin+r.my_stride-1)/2;
    middle = middle/my_stride*my_stride;
```

I.e. adds a stride to usual parallel_for approach.

Another obstacle is that `Sieve` functor holds a private copy of `Multiplies` class which should be reworked in order to match openmp approach.

E.g. `ParallelCountPrimes()` can be reworked with this parallel construct:

```
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        Multiples multiples(n); // per-thread copy, needs reworking to remain 'uninitialized'
        NumberType m = multiples.m;
        #pragma omp for
        for(NumberType i = multiples.m; i < n; i += multiples.m*CHUNKSIZE) {
            if( !multiples.is_initialized() )
                multiples.initialize( i ); // initialize by index of the first iteration
            NumberType window_size = m;
            NumberType end = i+multiples.m*CHUNKSIZE;
            if(end>n) end = n;
            for( NumberType j=i; j<end; j+=window_size ) { 
                if( j+window_size>end ) 
                    window_size = end-j;
                multiples.find_primes_in_window( j, window_size );
            }
        }                
    }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks, I generally agree with this approach. Though, copy-pasting of an example of that size seems radical while TBB (and even its example) will not disappear without any footprint in the Web and can be found even without direct link. Anyway, the answer turned out not very useful (for the particular question) since it is hard to translate the example to OpenMP